# K8s Helm - evaluating an inbuit variable inside an inbuilt variable

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to write an 'if' condition in helm to dynamically set my ingress host value depending on whether my namespace ends in -dev or -prod. However, when I use the below, it doesn't seem to be picking up the ".Release.Namespace" as the actual namespace, but instead just view it as the string itself which isn't helpful.

```
  {{ if hasSuffix "-prod" .Release.Namespace }} #If the namespace ends in "-prod"
  - hosts:
    - {{ .Values.ingress.domain }}
  {{ else }} #If the namespace contains "-dev"
```

I've tried various methods like using nested {{}} and also using tpl, but none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That seems like it should work.  What namespace are you using; what `helm install -n` option do you have?

Comment: Interesting when deploying with ArgoCD, it seems to have populated correctly now. However, when I tried running with helm template command, it was populating as a string. I guess this kind of makes sense because when running helm template I assume that inbuilt variable for the namesapce doesn't exist yet?